# Giving the wikipedia explanation of the input word via discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, wikipedia

```
import discord
import wikipedia

client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel(#channel id)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    while True:
        try:
            if str(message.channel) == "genel" and message.content != "" and message.content.startswith('!info'):
                parts = message.content.split()
                user_choice = str(parts[1:])
                user_choice.split()
                await message.channel.send(wikipedia.summary(user_choice, sentences=3))
                print("Succesful")
        except wikipedia.PageError:
            print("Wrong")
            await message.channel.send("You word is not on the list try another one.")

client.run("#client token")
```

There arent any problems. When I run the code no Errors show up and my bot turns online. Evendough everythink seems ok it does not give me what I want and nothing happens. Is it something other than the code or what? If it is what is wrong with my code.

Thanks!

Comment: The infinite loop seems unnecessary. Also, `user_choice.split()` doesn't actually do anything useful (just remove that line), and I don't think `str(parts[1:])` does what you want. Use `_, user_choice = message.content.split(maxsplit = 1)` instead to get the second part of the command.

Comment: So do you think that is the main reason or thats just some detail.

Comment: Had I thought that's the main reason, I would have posted an answer. Try printing out `message.content` to see if there's anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

The key point for no response is that `message.channel` is not only the name of channel, it is `discord.Textchannel` with properties. Therefore, `str(message.channel)` will always be false for the if statement. If you would like to check channel name, use `message.channel.name == 'genel'` in your case.
There are also lots of things that you can improve with your code.

1. if you want to check only one single channel in your if statement, **consider using channel id other than name**: `message.channel.id == your_channel_id` because what if somebody else uses your bot and also has a text channel named 'genel' in his/her server.
2. `message.content.startswith('!info')` will make sure the message content is not empty, so `message.content != ''` is redundant.
3. Your `parts = message.content.split(); user_choice = str(parts[1:]); user_choice.split()` seems confusing. But you can definitely simplify it since you shouldn't split a string into list, convert it back to string and split it again. And `user_choice.split()` does not assign to any variable, which it should.
4. You do not need to have a indefinite while loop for `on_message` event. The event will always trigger if there is a new message in channels. Your indefinite while loop will make the bot send the same answer indefinite amount of times and eventually be ratelimited by discord. (Or ratelimited by the wrapper, even Wikipedia)
5. Consider using [bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) rather than client since bot supports commands. You don't want to put all functionalities into `on_message` event.

Comment: G233 So I have tried what you advised and it still did not work. But I don't think the problem is your code. I have tried making a very simple discord bot that sends messages when I write **"!w "** and it did not worked. I think it is something with the **if  message.content.startswith('!w')** The **await message.channel.send()** code is fine because ı have tried sending message by writing a message to terminal and it worked just fine.

Comment: @TurkeyOncesaid Seems like you are missing intents. If your bot is used by your own (less than 100 servers), you can use `intents = discord.Intents.all()` and pass it into client like `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`. Also, don't forget to turn them on in your discord developer portal